# Should [iaps] be renamed [instrument-approaches]?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Currently [iaps](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iaps) x75 is used for "Instrument Approach Procedures (IAPs)".

And a newly created tag from two days ago, [instrument-approaches](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/instrument-approaches) x1, is not only more clear, but in line with the other "approach" tags *(shown below).* **Q:** Should [iaps](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iaps) be renamed [instrument-approaches](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/instrument-approaches)?

> [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree that [iaps](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iaps) is not a great name. It does not show up as a suggestion when starting to type *instrument...* or *approach...* into the tag field, so people have a hard time finding it. It therefore at least needs a synonym.

I think [instrument-approach](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/instrument-approach) (note the singular) would be the best name for it since that is in line with the other approach tag names (except for [visual-approaches](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visual-approaches), which also uses plural).

The full name of [instrument-approach-procedures](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/instrument-approach-procedures) is also possible, but I think it is unnecessarily long and AFAIK there is no real difference between the terms ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrument_approach) at least uses both terms for the same thing).

Comment: A while ago, there used to be a limit of 25 characters per tag, and the full form you mentioned would be over the limit, so I think the abbreviated form ended up getting used for that reason. However, the limit was later extended, so it's now viable.